# How many way we can emit javascript from controller at client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc....just learning. people use `registerclientscript or registerstartup` in asp.net web form to emit JavaScript at client side from server side method. so i like to know How many way we can emit JavaScript from controller's action method at client side. if possible please discuss all the ways with code snippet for better understanding. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be emitting JavaScript from the controller.  JavaScript is a UI-bound concept from the server's perspective and belongs in the view.

You can put it directly in the view itself, or in separate `.js` files which are referenced by the view.  (Or the layout, if it should be on many views.)

Emitting JavaScript from the controller tightly couples the controller to the view, and one of the main reasons to use the ASP.NET MVC Framework (or the MVC pattern in general, really) is to reduce the coupling between code and presentation.

I would even go so far as to say that `RegisterStartupScript` in WebForms is more often than not a poor design choice in the first place.  Even in WebForms, the client-side UI-bound concerns belong on the pages or on resource files (`.js` files in this case) referenced by the pages (or by the master page).  Client-side code shouldn't be unnecessarily obscured by server-side constructs.

**Edit:** Based on a comment you added to this answer, if you're looking to conditionally show/hide a block of JavaScript based on server-side logic then you would still do that in the view.  For example, your view might have something like this:

```
<!-- some HTML and other things up here -->
@if(Model.SomeCondition)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="someJSFile.js"></script>
}
<!-- some HTML and other things down here -->
```

In this case, that included JavaScript would only be rendered to the browser if `SomeCondition` on the model was true.  So `SomeCondition` would just be a property on the model which returns a boolean based on some internal logic.  (You *could* define the logic directly in the view itself, but in general it's best to keep as much of that on the model as possible and just have the view bind directly to model-exposed values.)

Comment: However, you may want to simply show a message of success. In that case, I usually have a `bool` property on my `viewmodel` to tell the view that stuff is alright. On the view, I have a small logic (an `if`) to decide whether to show the success message.

Comment: @AndreCalil: That's still not emitting JavaScript from the controller, though.  That's the controller simply populating the model with data and sending it to the view, which binds its values to that data.  That conditional can work whether it's wrapping JavaScript (for perhaps an alert pop-up) or any other element (perhaps a styled div with a success message).

Comment: *"Emitting JavaScript from the controller tightly couples the controller to the view"* - What's the difference in sending down JS vs sending down a view model? Both are *view* specific pieces of information which are sent by the controller. The controller isn't coupled at all, there is still a clear separation between the View/Controller - the only issue this introduces is the fact the view would depend on *something* sending down the JS (just like it depends on *something* to send down the model) which ultimately is poor design. I do agree though, it's not the right thing to do.

Comment: @David Yes, that's not javascript. I just wanted to show the OP that there are alternatives.

Comment: @James You could have a view that's not a *web view*, thus not understanding javascript. However, the viewmodel is a piece of software, is a DTO not bounded to a specific view.

Comment: @AndreCalil yep you could, but in that case the non-web view could simply ignore the JS. I am not for one second saying it's the correct thing to do, my point is it's not *really* coupling the controller to the view, they can both still exist independantly and you could easily swap out the controller for a different API.

Comment: @James: `"What's the difference in sending down JS vs sending down a view model?"` - JS is UI-bound.  It requires a client with a JS interpreter.  A view model is an object which contains data (and sometimes minimal functionality which is data-bound, such as calculated fields).  Any object which consumes the controller can use an object which contains data.  But only web-browsers use JavaScript.  It couples the controller to a specific presentation because the controller is assuming that the presentation uses JS.  It's not the controller's responsibility to know about that.

Comment: @James If the controller is sending something that just works for a few views, then it's coupled. I understand that it *works* and that it's not *wrong*, but it can be easily improved. =)

Comment: @AndreCalil agreed :)

Comment: i just need to is it possible or not.....is there any built-in function is there in mvc by which it can be achieve like webform.

Comment: @Thomas: It's not possible to do it *correctly*.  If you want to do things incorrectly, anything's game.  But in this design the JavaScript code belongs with the view (either directly placed therein or externally referenced as a resource).

Comment: @Thomas if you could give an example of *why* you need to do it then maybe there is a *correct* way of approaching what you need? e.g. via `HtmlHelper` extensions.

Comment: i worked with asp.net webform for long time and now i am learning asp.net mvc.i know that dynamically loading js file from server side code is possible by asp.net webform technology. so i asked it and looking for answer whether it is possible also in asp.net mvc or not ?

Comment: @Thomas: Dynamically referencing a JavaScript file in server-side code is a very different question from what was asked. If you want to conditionally render or not render a particular `script` tag in a view, you can wrap that part of the view in an `if` block and only render it when a certain condition it met on the model. (Something Andre was discussing in his replies.) In that case you're not emitting JavaScript from the controller, you're just conditionally showing/hiding it in the view based on the state of the model.